# Live id authendication for Sharepoint 2010

Tags: sharepoint-2010, localhost, claims-based-identity, liveid

Is it possible to use live id authentication for in premise SharePoint 2010 site . 
SharePoint site is not exposed ourside our network. Means after the authendication is it posible to redirect to localhost sharepoint /site ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Yes.

[Codeplex solution](http://spwla.codeplex.com/)

Comment: SharePoint site is not exposed ourside our network. Default redirect URL while registring application in http://msm.live.com/, need to be localhost. Is it possible ?. Means after the authendication is it posible to redirect to localhost sharepoint /site ?

Comment: Authentication is just that, a system that validates who you are. Where your system are doesn't really matter. You just need to ensure that you have access to the external authentication system, you don't need to provide external access to SharePoint

Comment: Thanks Paul, just a quick question, in that case while registering my application in msm.live.com, what can be my Domain Name*,DNS Name*,DNS Name* ? I tried with localhost and 127.0.0.1 it is not accepting :( . Codeplx solution won't wotk for SharePoint 2010.

Comment: There is a link in the codeplex page about configuring for SP2010. As for the DNS, thats down to your setup but localhost and 120.0.0.1 are not routeable from the Internet. You'll need to have a publicly accessible access point for LiveID to talk to (not the whole of SharePoint).

Answer (score 0):

Check here, source code available too:
http://sharepoint-live-authentication.shetabtech.com/

Live ID & OpenID Trusted Identity Provider and Claims Based Authentication for SharePoint 2010 & 2013.

It allows you and your members sign in to your SharePoint site with any OpenID provider or Windows Live ID. You can manage member's access before and after user's login to your site via SharePoint standard access pages and controls.